# SQL Server Transaction Logs

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

We are running an AlwaysOn SQL Server database with 2 servers. All runs great but we do have massive data changes every day. Our DB is around 60GB but we update data very often and take trans log backups every day but still growth exceeds 100GB to 300GB on transaction logs.

Is there any way to keep the transaction logs to 60GB (recommended size) and if it exceeds that, overwrite previous logs?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `log backups every day` and `growth exceeeds 100GB to 300GB` so you are making backups every day of logs with size > 60GB? Why do you need logs at all? 1) You are not making backups often 2) It requires less space to backup **full database**. You are not utilizing advantages of extremely fast (small), frequent log backups. Switch to `simple` maybe?

Comment: If you overwrite transaction log backups before the next full backup, the log backup would dbe useless since you'll only be able to recover to the last full/differential. The real question is how much data loss is acceptable (RPO). You'll need to schedule backups frequently enough to meet that SLA and enough space to accommodate it. Your current method allows for one day of data loss. If that's acceptable, daily full backups in the `SIMPLE` recovery model like @IvanStarostin suggested would be more space efficient.

Comment: SImple mode for Always on?

Comment: I was unaware that you can use Simple for an always on setup?   We used to run simple on very high transaction database and take daily backups but Always on requires Full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need Transaction Log for DR purpose then just make it in SIMPLE recovery model and take a full backup once in a day. and i don't understand why you are taking Transaction log once in a day.

I think so it should be with in at least 15 mins interval. Because you will loss of the data after last Transaction backup. so as a process and good feature of MS SQL Server, make it with small interval and move it to another server for safe purpose as part of Log-Shipping.

Comment: We need to use Always On which is why we have Transaction Logs set to full.   We do not need DR because of full backups are schedule.  Is taking trans backups on 15 min intervals hurt performance?  We do backups/trans log shipping on off hours to prevent locking, load, etc.

Comment: Chris, transaction log doesn't impacts performance issue. Always availability is for the availability of the platform. and Transaction & Full backups are for the disaster recovery, both are very different. so no worries about lock and all, its well designed & managed by MS SQL.

Comment: Thank you.  For best performance should I use: BACKUP LOG ? TO DISK = 'NUL:' WITH NO_COMPRESSION; or is there a more effective way to perform the back up.

Comment: Also, should I run the log backup on the secondary?

Comment: Please go through this:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2301/step-by-step-sql-server-log-shipping/

Comment: Thank you for the help!